# ng2 PDF viewer not showing all pages

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf-generation

I am trying to show pdf document through ng2-pdfviewer. Following is code for viewing:

```
<pdf-viewer [page]="this.vars.page"
                  [src]="this.vars.pdfSrc"

                  [show-all]="true"
                  [original-size]="true"

      ></pdf-viewer>
```

It is working fine when show-all is set to false. But when I set it to true it skips first two pages and always starts from third page. Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am suspicious that probably your error subsist in using the Typscript keyword `this` in a template. You don't need it in the template as it, because Angular will take care of making the binding between the class property (vars in your case) and the template, and 'this' is just not available.
So replace by the following:

```
<pdf-viewer [page]="vars.page"
                  [src]="vars.pdfSrc"
                  [show-all]="true"
                  [original-size]="true">
 </pdf-viewer>
```

Please read about '[this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript)'